# NGINX 301 на локальный ip адрес

Tags: nginx

Доброго времени суток!
Конфиг nginx:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name mydomain.com;
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
server {

server_name mydomain.com;
        listen 443;
        charset utf-8;
        default_type "text/html";
        ssl on;
        ssl_session_timeout 4m;
        ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";

        location /
        {
                root /var/www/mydomain/site;
                try_files  $uri/ $uri /index.html;
        }

         location /logs
        {
                alias /log/dir/logs;
                autoindex on;
        }
}
```

Если перейти по адресу https://mydomain.com/logs то браузер возвращает 301 на https://mylocalip/logs/

Загаловки ответа:

```
General:
Request URL:https://mydomain.com/logs
Request Method:GET
Status Code:301 Moved Permanently
Remote Address:myexternalip:443
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response Headers
view source
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:185
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Wed, 06 Dec 2017 06:48:04 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Location:https://mylocalip/logs/
Server:nginx/1.10.2
Strict-Transport-Security:max-age=31536000
```

Объясните почему, и как исправить?

Comment: Кэш сбрасывали? В другом браузере проверяли?

Comment: Да, конечно, проблема сохраняется

Comment: Это точно ваш nginx отвечает? У вас в конфиге нет HSTS

Comment: Спасибо за замечание. Случайно удалил строку add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000", обновил конфиг. Да, это мой nginx

Comment: "Да, это мой nginx" - тем не менее удостоверьтесь в этом. Например, сделайте `location = /a {return 200 'aa'}`

Comment: Возвращает 200 и аа.

Comment: А `return 200 "$http_host $server_name";`? Пока похоже на то, что где-то теряется заголовок `Host`

Comment: $http_host = mylocalip, $server_name = mydomain.com

Comment: `$http_host = mylocalip` — ну вот в этом и проблема. Выясняйте где потерялся заголовок `Host`. Может у вас перед nginx ещё что-то стоит? Или вы ходите в `http://mylocalip/`?

Comment: Спасибо за вашу помощь, действительно, впереди оказался еще один nginx, хотя до этого меня заверяли, что ничего нет. Помогла Ваша наводка и выход на администратора сети.

Answer (score 1):

Всему виной оказался стоящий впереди еще один экземпляр nginx, который проксировал запросы на нужный мне сервер. Спасибо всем участникам за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Вы столкнулись с нормальным поведением nginx, ведь в [документации](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_autoindex_module.html) к `ngx_http_autoindex_module` сказано:

> Модуль ngx_http_autoindex_module обслуживает запросы, **оканчивающиеся**
>   **слэшом (‘/’)**, и выдаёт листинг каталога. Обычно запрос попадает к
>   модулю ngx_http_autoindex_module, когда модуль ngx_http_index_module
>   не нашёл индексный файл.

Не думаю, что тут нужно что-то исправлять.

P.S. документация к `alias` рекомендует:

> Если location и последняя часть значения директивы совпадают то лучше
>   воспользоваться директивой root

так что это location правильнее написать так:

```
location /logs/ {
    alias /log/dir;
    autoindex on;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш развернутый комментарий!